# Navigation doesn't respond on iPad with iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar

Idea is very simple. I have navigation bar in universal storyboards with custom controls.

```
UIButton *menu = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
        [menu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [menu addTarget:self.viewDeckController action:@selector(toggleLeftView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIButton *refresh = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
        [refresh setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadPosts) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIButton *share = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
        [share setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [share addTarget:self action:@selector(showActionView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIBarButtonItem *menuBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menu];
        UIBarButtonItem *refreshBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:refresh];
        UIBarButtonItem *shareBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:share];

        UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacerLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        [negativeSpacerLeft setWidth:-10];

        UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacerRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        [negativeSpacerRight setWidth:-10];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacerLeft, menuBtn, nil];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacerRight, shareBtn, refreshBtn, nil];
```

Everything works correctly - navigation bar has implemented style and buttons/icons. But there is a problem with iPad and iOS 8 (works on iOS7). When I tap on any button, it does not respond. What I did wrong? It works as well on iPhone with iOS 7/8.

Comment: Are showActionView reloadPosts and  toggleLeftView messages even received by target object on iPad? Can you put breakpoints in those methods and see if they get hit? if they do, then your problem might be somewhere else, not in nav items.

Comment: Actually I made a new method with NSLog inside instead self.viewDeckcontroller toggleLeftView. It doesn't respond at all - I mean - this method is not called.